# Raster statistics for polygon areas PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

I'm trying to get zonal raster statistics for each polygon area. 
I have used the following method from [this site:](https://duncanjg.wordpress.com/2012/10/29/working-with-raster-data-in-postgis/#comment-1457)

```
SELECT bufid, (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(ST_Clip(rast, geom, true))).*
FROM rasttable, buftable
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)
GROUP BY bufid
```

This works great for a test area with 11 polygons.
However, when I try to run it on the same raster with a larger table of polygons (count of 190,000) I keep getting the following error:

> **ERROR:  rt_raster_from_two_rasters: The two rasters provided do not have the same alignment
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function st_clip(raster,integer[],geometry,double precision[],boolean) line 8 at RETURN**

How might I go about resolving this?

I'm using PostGIS 2.2.0 on PostgreSQL 9.4.4, Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: What SRID are you using. I am guessing it is not 32648, which is possibly why you are not getting anything for rast_alignto.

Comment: Apologies, I am using 4326, I have changed the question to show that. 
I'm not sure that would affect the query either anyway?

Comment: I would be surprised if your raster is in 4326. If so, you might be better of transforming it to a cartesian projection first, along with your geometry.  What is ST_Extent(rast) telling you? Your second query obviously doesn't work because the last FROM refers to ras69 instead of ref.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have discovered a solution and added this as an answer below. This didn't use the linked answer in the question so I have removed this part from the question for clarity sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a solution which works:

```
  SELECT x.bufid, (ST_SummaryStatsAgg(x.intersectx,1,true)).* 
  FROM
       (SELECT bufid, ST_Intersection(rast,1,ST_AsRaster(geom, rast),1) as intersectx
       FROM rasttable, buftable
       WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, rast)) as x
  WHERE x.intersectx IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY bufid
```

I think the issue was with the geometry of the vector data (**buftable**) whereby there was no intersection occurring between it and the raster data for some rows (due to invalid geometry?).

The following part takes care of that issue:

> ```
> WHERE x.intersectx IS NOT NULL
> ```